# how to kill mysql process using mac

Tags: mysql

I used `ps ax | grep mysql` to check whether mysql process exists and i found

`5323 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep mysql` .

I would like to kill the process but the number changed automatically.

When i enter `ps ax | grep mysql`, the content changed like

`5507 s000  S+     0:00.00 grep mysql`

BTW, i have tried the way to deleted mysql that is the most popular way on the internet. But the mysql process still on my computer.

Anyone could give me a hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: if you are install mysql via brew, you can use `mysql.server stop` to stop the process.

Answer (score 11):

just did it. I tried:
1) get pid

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3306
```

or

```
ps ax | grep mysql
```

2) `sudo kill -9 [pid]`
It seems that I killed it right? but wait... when show mysql pid again, it comes back again with a different pid. Then I remember mysql in `system preferences`. Press the icon, and press stop server button. SUCCESS

EDIT: it is here

[image: bing searching results]

Comment: "mysql in system preferences" .. Where is that?

Comment: @Gangesh I posted a figure. I don't have mac at hand right now, but bing give the same result as my mac has.

Comment: This icon is not default, thats why I couldn't find it. I solved my problem by terminal :)  Thanks though.

Comment: @Gangesh maybe it depends on the software version. If one has this icon in system preferences, mysql has to be stopped there.

Comment: You saved my day. I have tried all other method but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your output shows the `grep` process searching for "mysql" in the result from ps. That means, you just see the process showing you the processes you search for.

mysql is not running here, so you don't get it listed.

And you can't kill that process because it has finished as soon as you return to the shell. The next time you issue the same command, a new `ps` process spawns and a new `grep` process spawns with another pid than the one before.

Comment: so could i understand your words like mysql process doesn't run my computer anymore

Comment: Correct. See my second paragraph

Comment: this is not a "problem" of `ps`, neither of `grep`. It's just the way it works: `ps` always shows _all_ processes running at that moment (including itself and `grep` which you started together with `ps`). And grep is just something that filters text. you connect them both with the `|` pipe, so the output of `ps` becomes the input of `grep`. And that just filters out every line that is not matched. So in the end, it finds at least itself (because `grep mysql` matches `"mysql"`)