# How to stop MacOs to create/delete mysql instances?

Tags: mysql, macos, pid, macos-ventura

I'm using MacOS Ventura 13.0 with the Apple M1 Max chip, and I would like (and tried) to use MySQL Workbench. Maybe this problem is related to the bug ["Crash after a select" at mysql.com](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109671). However...

When in the Terminal[*] I run the command `ps aux|grep mysql` multiple time in a few seconds then the PID number constantly increases each time I run the command:

```
input$    ps aux|grep mysql
output$   30364 ttys000      0:00.00 grep mysql

(after few seconds) 
input$    ps aux|grep mysql
output$   30366 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql

(after few seconds)
input$    ps aux|grep mysql
output$   30368 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql

...

(after few minutes)
input$    ps aux|grep mysql
output$   36322 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql

...

(after few hours)
input$    ps aux|grep mysql
output$   71252 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql

...
```

It's very strange. Also, this doesn't allow me to close/kill all the running mysql processes because a new mysql process is created each few seconds, even using `sudo killall -9 mysql`. Furthermore, in the /tmp/ folder, each few seconds there are created and deleted the mysql.sock.lock and mysqlx.sock.lock files in an automatic way!

I read and tried many possible solutions** (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876024/how-to-kill-mysql-process-using-mac), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100948/how-do-you-stop-mysql-on-a-mac-os-install) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924580/uninstall-mysql-from-macos)) including [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1695533/mysql-process-wont-die-on-mac), but the mysql PID increasing continues to happen.

How can I solve the problem? Any advice?

---

Notes: I migrated from an old Intel-based Mac to an Arm-based Mac.

[*]

The Terminal, if this info can help you to help me, outputs this when I launch it:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

[**]

Here are a few things I tried in order to stop mysql to create/delete new processes and files, without success:

*Attempt 1* - Using the System Settings widget, but the Start/Stop button of MySQL Workbench didn't worked at all. I also tried to deactivate mysqld_safe in System Settings > General > Login Items without success.

*Attempt 2* - Installing and unistalling MySQL (Workbench Arm64 version) via homebrew (`brew`) and binary file (downloaded .pkg), and restarting the OS many times.

*Attempt 3* - Using the Terminal:

```
(with mysql installed via homebrew)
$ brew services stop mysql
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.json
Warning: Service `mysql` is not started.

$ mysql.server stop
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!

$ /usr/local/bin/mysql.server stop
-bash: /usr/local/bin/mysql.server: No such file or directory

$ sudo killall -9 mysql
Password: ******
No matching processes were found
```

*Other*

```
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

$ brew services start mysql
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/<MyUserName>/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` exited with 5.

$ sudo brew services start mysql
Warning: Taking root:admin ownership of some mysql paths:
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.32/bin
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.32/bin/mysqld_safe
  /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql
  /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql/bin
  /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked/mysql
This will require manual removal of these paths using `sudo rm` on
brew upgrade/reinstall/uninstall.
Warning: mysql must be run as non-root to start at user login!
==> Successfully started `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql)

$ mysqld_safe
2023-02-21T23:19:50.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/<MyMacName>.lan.err'.
2023-02-21T23:19:50.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
2023-02-21T23:19:51.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/<MyMacName>.lan.pid ended
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Solved, at least to make MySQL to work on my Arm64 Apple Silicon!

Among others, the problem was related to permission denied to mysql files and folders.

After having installed the pkg [mysql-8.0.31-macos12-x86_64.dmg](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) (on the Arm64 Apple Silicon), I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35027185/502052).

Now, it *seems* to work *!*